# Using agm-core (Angular Google Maps) how can i use arrow head on agm-polyline

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am using Angular5 and using agm-core to draw google maps
using this code to draw polylines

```
<agm-polyline [strokeColor]="path.color" 
                strokeWeight="2" *ngFor="let path of paths">              
                <agm-polyline-point *ngFor="let pt of path.points"                     
                    [latitude]="pt.lat" 
                    [longitude]="pt.lng">
                  </agm-polyline-point>
  </agm-polyline>
```

This draws lines on the map as follows

[image]

I want that the lines will have Arrow heads

Is that possible with agm-core ?

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? did you able to add arrow head  in polyline

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use for this agm-marker component with [iconUrl] input attribute.

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let path of paths" [latitude]="path.points[0].lat" 
[longitude]="path.points[0].lng" [iconUrl]='../assets/my_arrow.png'></agm-marker>
```

Something like that

Comment: This one draws only markers, but you can combine them together. Just place both of them in html template.
`<agm-marker>...</agm-marker><agm-polyline>...</agm-polyline>`

Comment: I think this is not going to work since the arrow head is always going to point to the same direction , isn't it?